# QWebView pop-up window asking for credentials

Tags: qtwebkit, qwebview, createwindow

I have a QTWebkit simple browser that works until it opens a pop-up windows inside a security page (with login/password) and the new window redirects me to input the credentials again.
I can't find a way/examples/books/forums that deals with this problem.

Could anyone point me to a direction, or provide a simple example on how to keep the logged user to access the pop-up/new window resources in the web page ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try replacing the QtWebkit's default NetworkAccessManager, then process the authenticationRequired signal.